# Whats the correct way to use net.Conn.Read for persistant TCP sockets

Tags: sockets, go, tcp

I have a working TCP socket setup on my Go server. I accept an incoming connection, run a for loop and read incoming data using the net.Conn.Read function.

But it just doesn't make sense to me. How does it know the full message has been received in order to continue with a return of message size?

This is my code currently:

```
 func (tcpSocket *TCPServer) HandleConnection(conn net.Conn) {

    println("Handling connection! ", conn.RemoteAddr().String(), " connected!")    
    recieveBuffer := make([]byte, 50) // largest message we ever get is 50 bytes

    defer func() {          
        fmt.Println("Closing connection for: ", conn.RemoteAddr().String())
        conn.Close()
    }()

    for {
        // how does it know the end of a message vs the start of a new one?
        messageSize, err := conn.Read(recieveBuffer) 
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        if messageSize > 0 { // update keep alive since we got a message
            conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second * 5))    
        }
    }
}
```

Lets say my application sends a message which is 6 bytes long (could be any size). How does `conn.Read` know when its received the end of said message to then continue?

My experience mainly lies in C#, so Go is but unusual here. For my C# application the messages have the size of the message contained in first byte, then i use a for loop to read the remaining bytes up to message size.

Yet the above code in Go seems to get the full message and continues - it some how automatically knows the size of my message?

I am really confused how this is happening or if its just working by luck when i'm actually approaching it wrong.

All my messages have the header in the first byte stating the size of the message. But it seems i don't need it on a Go server, am i misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: TCP works the same regardless of language. It’s up to you to properly handle the message boundaries.

Comment: So why do all the examples use Read(someBuffer) since it doesn't even handle such things? When would Read ever be used if you can't tell it the boundaries? I can't find examples of how to actually do it correctly.

Comment: I don’t understand, how else would you read from a TCP connection? That’s how TCP works, it’s a stream protocol and there is simply no concept of messages. If you need message envelopes of some sort you use a higher level protocol.

Comment: Because it is passing live game data over a socket. I need a two way channel which http doesn't give. TCP socket seems like the only thing for it. So i don't know why TCP would be a bad choice for putting messages in it ? What else is there?

Comment: TCP isn't a bad choice, you just have to handle the message framing in the higher level protocol, because it's not part of TCP. You've already defined a primitive protocol here, you have length prefixed messages, so use that rather than guessing. Maybe part of the misunderstanding is that you have Read returning "messageSize", but that's not a message size, its simply the number of bytes read, which may be more or less than expected. (though it will probably match giving your limited payload size)

Comment: Well due to the infrequency of the messages, Read seems to return a message size and is writing the full message to the buffer. But i don't know how - i think i'm getting lucky due to it reading End Of File. But there is no other method for Conn to read incoming messages so am a bit confused how to read the data with my current primitive protocol.

Comment: This is because `Read` is the basic primitive method for receiving data, basically equivalent to `recv` on a socket. Yes, you're getting lucky because of the small message size, regardless you should strictly follow your protocol just like you would in any language. I see what you're looking for now. I'll post an answer on how to read your proposed protocol.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

TCP doesn't provide any message framing, it's up to you to buffer the stream and parse the messages according to whatever protocol you've defined.

When parsing a TCP stream, it's often useful to immediately wrap the connection in a [`bufio.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader), as not only can it make reading more efficient, but it provides you with more useful methods. An example of how you could parse your protocol could be:

```
buff := make([]byte, 50)
c := bufio.NewReader(conn)

for {
    // read a single byte which contains the message length
    size, err := c.ReadByte()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // read the full message, or return an error
    _, err := io.ReadFull(c, buff[:int(size)])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fmt.Printf("received %x\n", buff[:int(size)])
}
```

Comment: Ah nice that looks like what i was looking for! Thank you :)