# TCP connection appears to be reading too many bytes at once

Tags: go, tcp

I'm writing an FTP server in Go and I've run into a problem when listing the files/directories. What seems to be happening is that the server is sending the files each separately and correctly but when reading them from the connection, they get read multiple at a time.

I've tried changing the buffer size as well as sending a confirmation before sending each file name yet when reading from the connection it ends up reading more bytes than expected.

This is the relative part from the server:

```
for _, fn := range files {
    conn.Write([]byte(fn.Name()))
}
```

In the code above, `files` is `[]os.FileInfo` from `ioutil.ReadDir("./")` to get the files in the current directory. When tested this sends the correct file name as well as the correct bytes for each name.

On the client I have this:

```
var buf [256]byte
for i := 0; i < int(amnt); i++ {
    n, err = conn.Read(buf[:])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error getting files: %s\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(buf[:n]))
}
```

`int(amnt)` is just an `int` for how many files are in the directory and is correct.

The server sends everything correctly so I am sure that the problem lies in reading into `buf` but I can't figure out why it would be reading in more than one file name at a time.

Comment: That’s how TCP works, it is a stream protocol. This code is expecting every file name to be exactly 256 bytes.

Comment: Your sender is just writing all the file names out one after the other with nothing between them and your receiver is just grabbing chunks of data without looking at them. There's no code anywhere to either place separators in the output or locate separators in the input!

Comment: See related question [Whats the correct way to use net.Conn.Read for persistant TCP sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585244/whats-the-correct-way-to-use-net-conn-read-for-persistant-tcp-sockets),

Answer (score 1):

One strategy to address this could be to develop a loose structured protocol which will involve having the client delineate files and the server parse files.  This might be done by sending a new line after each file that the client writes.  This way the server can scan lines from the TCP connection using go's [`Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewScanner):

```
for _, fn := range files {
    conn.Write([]byte(fn.Name()))
    conn.Write([]byte(`\n`))
}
```

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)
for {
        if ok := scanner.Scan(); !ok {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
    fmt.Println("Scanning ended")
```

---

Go makes this possible because the [TCP connection](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPConn) implements the [io.Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) interface.